# Detect if a HttpServlet's response is received successfully?

Tags: java, http, servlets, tcp

How can I detect if the response sent by an HttpServlet (e.g. the result from doPost() or doGet()) is correctly received by the client? I currently have the client send an 'ack' request back to the server upon receiving a certain response to a request, however this is probably redundant.

I believe Tcp already sends acks, and by that the server should know if the response is delivered, or is this not how it works and I have to keep sending acknowledgements manually ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on TCP. I would have the client generate a `sha1()` of the content it received, then send that to the server to confirm a successful receipt.

TCP's built in checksums are not good enough, they're designed for extremely high performance and sacrifice reliability to achieve it.

Comment: But isn't TCP completely reliable, as that it doesn't lose any data or else it will throw an error?

Comment: TCP is not completely reliable. It will very rarely lose data, but it absolutely does loose data every now and then without reporting any error. How frequent depends on your connection type - with CAT6 Ethernet it will pretty much never happen, with copper phone lines it can happen fairly often. If you have a faulty router somewhere it might happen several times each day.

Comment: Basically if you care about reliability you should be doing the checksum yourself, and with a reliable hashing function like `sha1`.

Comment: The biggest problem is TCP doesn't report errors, it fixes them silently. So if your switch is faulty and causing corruption billions of times every day, you won't know because TCP detected and fixed it. Except every now and then it will fail to detect the corruption - the algorithms used by TCP are not good enough to be relied on.

Comment: I wasn't really talking about needing integrity of the data, but more of a confirmation of whether any data was received at all (in case of TCP this is all or nothing right?). I will now keep with my approach as mentioned in my question, how redundant this feels to me.